# Google payments got error

Tags: android, payment, android-pay

I included in project Google payments like in guide described - [guide](https://developers.google.com/payments/setup). In runtime when I try to open it, I got DEVELOPER ERROR in onActivityResult. What the reason I can't guess. Hope anyone can help.

Comment: Post the code what you tried with error stacktrace..

Comment: Is there any error number?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda  Error: Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}
this is the error which I got in intent in onActivityResult

Comment: @motis10 answered

Comment: Please try to verify that your SHA1 key in the developer console match the one generated from my debug/release.keystore file.